# pass parameter in django template URL tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass a parameter to a django URL in the template. The URL is configured as:

```
url(r'^reviewrecord/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.MyView, name='reviewrecord')
```

Now, I am calling this from a ajax block in a javascripyt function. The javascript function is declared as:

```
function EditDialog(pk) {
    $.ajax(
      {
         url: "{% url 'reviewrecord' pk=pk %}",
         type: "POST",
         data: postData,
       });
}
```

Doing this results in:

```
Reverse for 'reviewrecord' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['reviewrecord/$', 'reviewrecord/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

However, I have verified that if I hard-code the `pk` value, it works. So, replacing the url paranmeter with something like:

```
url: "{% url 'reviewrecord' pk=5 %}",
```

This works. So, I am somehow unable to refer to the passed `pk` value in the JS function in the URL tag.

In light of the comments below, I can do the following:

```
function EditDialog(pk) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                pk: pk
            },
            success: function(formHtml){
                //place the populated form HTML in the modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(formHtml);
                $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
            },
            dataType: 'html'
            });
```

This does show the dialog where everything is populated correctly.

I am not sure how to achieve something similar with this case. I tried something like:

```
var postData = $("#review-form").serializeArray();
$.ajax(
            {
                url: "{% url 'reviewrecord' pk %}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  data: postData,
                  pk: pk,
            });
```

This was more like a desperate attempt but it did not work.

**EDIT**

THE HTML template is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Cloud | Review data {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

    <div id="dialog" class="modal" title="Edit" style="display:none">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Review Uploaded Image</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "project.css" %}" />

    <script>

        // using jQuery            
        function EditDialog(pk) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                pk: pk
            },
            success: function(formHtml){
                //place the populated form HTML in the modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(formHtml);
                $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
            },
            dataType: 'html'
            });

            $("#dialog").submit(function(e)
            {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                        }
                    }
                });

                var postData = $("#review-form").serializeArray();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "{% url 'reviewrecord' pk=pk %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postData,

                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        //var transformed = data.replace('/-1/g', pk.toString())
                        $('.modal-body').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
                e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
            });
            return false;
            }
    </script>

    {% if reviews %}
     <div class="function-page">
         <div class="table-form">
                <div class="function-container">
                    {% render_table reviews %}
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="form">
                        <div class="figcaption">Looks like you are all caught up! There is nothing to review.</div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It seems that pk has no value passed. Are you sure it has a value?

Comment: Tried that as well. results in: `Reverse for 'reviewrecord' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['reviewrecord/$', 'reviewrecord/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

Comment: How is this surprising? The Django template tag is rendered on the server side, long before the JS can run.

Comment: Right...So, what would be a way to pass this parameter in such a case then...

Comment: The way I've done this in the past is to put an impossible value in the template tag - eg `00000` - and then use the string `.replace()` method in the JS to replace it with the actual value.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I also edited the question to show things that worked

Comment: Well now I'm no longer sure what you're asking. What happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Django \`reverse\` in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724383/calling-django-reverse-in-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

For a template tag like `{% url 'reviewrecord' pk=pk %}`, whatever is between the brackets, like the `pk` variable, has to be rendered ahead of time. It can't be passed from javascript.

Now, as you showed in your second example, you can pass the data through a GET or POST request:

```
function EditDialog(pk) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
            pk: pk
        },
...
```

which will GET a url like `/populatereviewform?pk=5` where pk=5.

If you really want django to give your a url from a javascript call, you have to create another view.
Javascript:

```
function EditDialog(pk) { //pk=5
 $.get("{% url 'geturl' %}",{pk:pk}) // /geturl?pk=5
  .done(function(data){ // url returns data
    var the_url = data; // /reviewrecord/5
    $.ajax({
      url: the_url,
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
  });
 });
}
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^geturl/$', views.get_url_view, name='get_url'),
```

views.py:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
def get_url_view(request):
  pk = request.GET['pk']
  the_url = reverse('reviewrecord', kwargs{'pk':pk})
  return HttpResponse(the_url)
```

Though that seems like a lot of work for a variable you could pass through GET or POST data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the problem is when I open the dialog the first time, it works great. On the second time, the primary key is not updated for the new value. Essentially `$.get("{% url 'geturl' %}",{pk:pk}) // /geturl?pk=5` keeps the primary key to the old value for some reason unknown to me yet.

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem somewhere in your Javascript. I can't be sure unless I see the whole project. 2 things to test: 1. does `http://yoursite.com/geturl/?pk=5` give the right url? 2. see if you can call the `EditDialog()` function with different pk values. Maybe create some buttons with `<a href="javascript:EditDialog(3)">`

Comment: All those things did work. In the end, I ended up storing the `pk` value in a sessionStore and that worked. The ajax part somehow never had access to the newer `pk` value even though the rest of the JS script did. Maybe it has not been rendered....not sure at all...