# Ignoring variable type in Django's reverse function

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to send the URL information by using the URL name and proceed them in JavaScript. So i will not set the true parameters while generating it by reverse function which trigs error because of th wrong data types:

```
reverse("url-name", args = ["{0}", "{1}", "{2}"]) # The first parameter should be number
```

Javascript:

```
url = url.replace("{0}", 34)\
      .replace("{1}", "Cem")\
      .replace("{2}", "Şebinkarahisar");
```

Is there any way to ignore data types while generating them in Django?

Thanks.

Comment: may have a look at [Django reverse() for JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795701/django-reverse-for-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [django.js](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django.js).
It's an application doing what you want:

```
{% load js %}
{% django_js %}
<script>
    Django.onReady(function(){
        console.log(Django.url('my-url', param1, param2, param3));
        console.log(Django.url('my-url', [param1, param2, param3]));
        console.log(Django.url('my-url', {
            param1: param1,
            param2: param2,
            param3: param3
        })
    });
</script>
```